# Using rsync --remove-source-files & --include-from= options together

Tags: centos7, rsync

I have a central CentOS 7 backup server, where I run the following `rsync` command in a script to pull the Application logs from 100's of Linux machines and then delete them.

```shell
rsync --remove-source-files --include-from=/tmp/$MACHINE_file.lst \
  -v -a -l -K --rsh=ssh --stats $MACHINE:/ $BACKUPDIR/$MACHINE
```

I generate `/tmp/file.lst` on the central backup machine for each machine using other script; It contains the following directories and files to be backed up.

```
+ /data1/
+ /data2/
+ /data2/sample/
- *
```

But recently I encountered a big problem where the `/tmp` partition on the central backup server became full due to some other problem and hence `/tmp/$MACHINE_file.lst`  could not be created. This created a problem where `rsync` started deleting the files from `/` partition on the source machines. Any idea why?

Comment: Perhaps if you follow arg `--include-from=...` with a redundant `--exclude='*'` it will guarantee that if the .lst file fails, you will still have the "exclude everything" default working.

Answer (score 0):

- tmp directory filled up and file.lst could not be created
- rsync ignored the --include-from directive since that file did not exist and included *everything* on the source since you specified the / directory in your command
- unfortunately you also specified --remove-source-files
- since those files didn't exist on your target it did exactly as you asked - synced everything to the target and deleted everything on the source.

Comment: Thanks , can i specify /tmp directory in  the command , instead / , will rsync still consider only those directories and files listed in the --include-from=/tmp/$MACHINE_file.lst